# X11rdp/xrdp with aad-login -> pam authentication fails (xrdp_mm_process_login_response: login failed)

Tags: login, pam, failed, xrdp

We are implementing a solution that allows users to login via `aad-login` (Azure Active Directory login) following this guide:
https://github.com/bureado/aad-login

Everything works fine - I can login via SSH to the Ubuntu machine (14.04 LTS) with AAD credentials.

The login is enabled through this line in the `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`

```
auth sufficient pam_exec.so debug expose_authtok seteuid /usr/local/bin/aad-login
```

Further we want to extend the AAd login via xrdp (using `X11rdp`) - But login with AAD Credentials is not working.

X11rdp with local users is working fine (so `xrdp-sesman` is configured fine)

It seems that the username from the xrdp login screen is not passed to the "aad-login" (`/usr/local/bin/aad-login`)

Logging within common-auth says no username/password provided with AAD user. (As mentioned, logon with local users works fine)

All users are in `tsusers` group (also the AAD Users)

I have to add that we had already a test machine that worked fine, but we can not reproduce the scenario - so something seems to be missing in this configuration...

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?